# How can I pass numpy array from flask to javascript and convert it to javascript array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, flask

I would like to ask how can I pass output.tolist() as javascript array to javascript ?

Below is my code in python flask ( The label lists is predefined and the values list is the numpy array that I want to convert to javascript array):

```
 @app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
    def predict():
        #dummy data
        arr = np.array([103, 85, 204, 333, 107,33,444,123,152,532,223,464])
        df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
        # a prediction model that will return a numpy array output
        output = model.model_prediction(df)
        #dummy data
        label_list = ['12/2021','01/2022','02/2022','03/2022','04/2022','05/2022','06/2022','07/2022','08/2022','09/2022','10/2022','11/2022']
        values_list = json.dumps(output.tolist())
        json_output = {
            "labels": label_list,
            "values": values_list
        }
        return jsonify(request.form)
```

I will be sending the train data through AJAX, once the python finished processing the data, it will return me a numpy array, and I want to convert it to a javascript array when it gets passed to javascript.

Comment: are you not already doing that? You're sending it as a list it looks like: `output.tolist()`

Comment: I thought so, but the javascript side is not recognizing it as array

Comment: What does it see now? You might not need to use `json.dumps`, that might make the front end see it as a string.

Answer (score -1):

Send your Python array to your client, and call JSON.parse on it. I don't use Python so I can't give more detail than that but this should point you in the right direction.